# Cut a hole on SKNode and update its physicsBody in Swift

Tags: swift, cut, skphysicsbody

I'm creating an app which will contains some holes on the image.
Since the code is very big I've created this simple code which has the same idea.
This code has an image with it's physicsBody set already.

What I would like is in the touchesBegan function to draw some transparent circles at the touched location and update the image physicsBody (making a hole on the image).

I've found several codes in objective C and UIImage, can someone help with Swift and SKSpriteNode?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Icon.png")
        let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
        node.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        addChild(node)

        node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: texture.size())
        node.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {



    }

}
```

Comment: Physics bodies have no effect on the visual appearance of a node. Are you trying to cut visual holes in the node, physical holes in the physics body, or both?

Comment: I'm trying to cut both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to apply a mask and render that to an image and update your `SKSpriteNode's` texture. Then use that texture to determine the physics body. This process however will not be very performant.

For example in `touchesBegan` you can say something like:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        if let node = self.nodeAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self.scene!)) as? SKSpriteNode{

            let layer = self.layerFor(touch, node: node) // We'll use a helper function to create the layer

            let image = self.snapShotLayer(layer) // Helper function to snapshot the layer
            let texture = SKTexture(image:image)
            node.texture = texture

            // This will map the physical bounds of the body to alpha channel of texture. Hit in performance
            node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: node.texture!, size: node.size) 
        }
    }
```

Here we just get the node and look at the first touch, you could generalize to allow multi touch, but we then create a layer with the new image with transparency, then create a texture out of it, then update the node's physics body.

For creating the layer you can say something like:

```
    func layerFor(touch: UITouch, node: SKSpriteNode) -> CALayer
    {
        let touchDiameter:CGFloat = 20.0

        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: node.size)
        layer.contents = node.texture?.CGImage()

        let locationInNode = touch.locationInNode(node)

        // Convert touch to layer coordinate system from node coordinates
        let touchInLayerX = locationInNode.x + node.size.width * 0.5 - touchDiameter * 0.5 
        let touchInLayerY = node.size.height - (locationInNode.y + node.size.height * 0.5) - touchDiameter * 0.5

        let circleRect = CGRect(x: touchInLayerX, y: touchInLayerY, width: touchDiameter, height: touchDiameter)
        let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: circleRect)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: node.size.width, height: node.size.height)
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: shapeLayer.frame)
        path.appendPath(circle)
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
        shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

        layer.mask = shapeLayer
        return layer
    }
```

Here we just set the current texture to the contents of a `CALayer` then we create a `CAShapeLayer` for the mask we want to create. We want the mask to be opaque for most of the layer but we want a transparent circle, so we create a path of a rectangle then add a circle to it. We set the `fillRule` to `kCAFillRuleEvenOdd` to fill everything but our circle.

Lastly, we render that layer to a UIImage that we can use to update our texture.

```
    func snapShotLayer(layer: CALayer) -> UIImage
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, 0.0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        layer.renderInContext(context!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
```

Maybe someone will provide a more performant way of accomplishing this, but I think this will work for a lot of cases.

Comment: beyowulf your solution worked perfectly though I thought it would be smaller and maybe more simple. I guess there may be a easier way to do that right? Nonetheless I'll wait a while to see if somebody else or even you have a easier way, otherwise I'll mark that as correct! much appreciated!